# Coding Exercise: Timbits-Fix the bugs and pass all of the tests

Tags: python

I've been looking at this program for a while now and I can't seem to find what is wrong with the code. I've checked the numbers and they are fine. I almost think its a quotes or parentheses. I would appreciate the help. Here's the code:

```
# step 1: get the input
timbitsLeft = int(input())

# step 2: initialize the total cost

totalCost = 0             

# step 3: buy as many large boxes as you can
bigBoxes = int(timbitsLeft / 40)

totalCost = totalCost + bigBoxes * 6.19    # update the total price

timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 40 * bigBoxes  # calculate timbits still needed
# step 4, can we buy a medium box?

if timbitsLeft >= 20:                

    totalCost = totalCost + 3.39
    timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 20

if timbitsLeft > 10:                # step 5, can we buy a small box?

    totalCost = totalCost + 1.99
    timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 20
# step 6

totalCost = totalCost + timbitsLeft * 20 

print(totalCost)
```

This is the error I get:
Did not pass tests. Please check details below and try again.
Results for test case 1 out of 11

Input:
10
Program executed without crashing.

Program output:
200.0

Expected this correct output:
1.99

Result of grading: Output line 1, value 200.0, did not match expected value 1.99

Comment: There's not quite enough info for us to help here. In your own words what is this code supposed to do? Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Also you should go to some effort to follow the flow of your code, go through line by line and see what happens for various input types. This practice of debugging in this manner will likely be of great use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an output of 200 because you do not have enough money to buy a large box or medium box. You then check to see if you can buy a small box, but you only have 10 timbits, so the if statement, `if timbitsLeft > 10: # step 5, can we buy a small box?`, is not true so you cannot buy a small box either. Then you do the calculation `totalCost = totalCost + timbitsLeft * 20` which gives you a value of 200.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like your mistake is

```
if timbitsLeft > 10:
```

Your input is 10 so you have 10 timbits left,
but you need more than 10 to go further into the if statement,
therefore its not doing anything except:

```
totalCost = totalCost + timbitsLeft * 20
```

and thats basically

```
totalCost = 0 + 10 * 20
```

and that is indeed 200

you might need

```
if timbitsLeft >= 10:
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't read all of the information given to you.

The numbers are wrong for the small box and the price of 1 box.

```
if timbitsLeft > 10:                # step 5, can we buy a small box?

totalCost = totalCost + 1.99
timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 20  (<---- the problem. it should be: - 10)
```

-10 is the amount of small boxes.

```
totalCost = totalCost + timbitsLeft * 20 (<---- the problem. it should be: *.2)
print(totalCost)
```

.2 is the price of a single box.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution to the cscircles "Coding Exercise: Timbits"

```css
timbitsLeft = int(input()) # step 1: get the input
totalCost = 0              # step 2: initialize the total cost

# step 3: buy as many large boxes as you can
if timbitsLeft >=40:
    bigBoxes = int(timbitsLeft / 40)
    totalCost = totalCost + bigBoxes * 6.19    # update the total price
    timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 40 * bigBoxes  # calculate timbits still needed

if timbitsLeft >= 20:                # step 4, can we buy a medium box?
    mediumBoxes = int(timbitsLeft / 20)
    totalCost = totalCost + mediumBoxes * 3.39
    timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - 20 * mediumBoxes
if timbitsLeft >= 10:                # step 5, can we buy a small box?
    smallBoxes = int(timbitsLeft / 10)
    totalCost = totalCost + smallBoxes*1.99
    timbitsLeft = timbitsLeft - smallBoxes*10

totalCost = totalCost + timbitsLeft * 0.2 # step 6
print(totalCost)                         # step 7
```

Comment: I think this is not an answer. The OP wanted to “find what is wrong with the code”; I can see the corrected code, but what was wrong with it?